# Why are my flags on code posted as a comment by OP declined by moderator?

Tags: discussion, flags

I see many of the flags raised by me which was for posting code as **comment** instead of editing the post *[not much in my case since the posts I reviewed are very less, but when I say most of them, I mean the flags I raised pointing this should have been an edit in the question]*.

Basically most of these will be done by new users, since they are less aware of editing the question feature. But posting the code as comment will indeed be a problem to the users who try to answer the question and which would be messy to read too.

Is there any particular reason for the flags raised to point **that this code posted as comment should've been edited in question?**

Comment: They probably got declined because *you* can do the editing yourself, if you wish to. There's no reason to get a moderator involved.

Comment: @Rob I can edit it, I agree, but I cannot remove that right? The main intention of posting the flag will be to remove unwanted things from SO and keep the site clean and also to make the other users to read the question comfortably. IMHO, we are asking moderators to remove these stuffs since we cannot..

Comment: If the code has been edited into question, moderator should understand if you use an obsolete flag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The last time you flagged such a comment was last year. Here is what you said:

> Should be edited in question.. – Guruprasad Rao Sep 30 '15 at 9:19

Another moderator handled this flag, but right off the bat I can see why it was declined. You never said you had already edited the comment content into the question yourself. In fact, your message is implying that you weren't going to do so yourself and instead you wanted *us* to do it for you.

You could even just use an "obsolete" flag instead of typing a custom message and that would have been acceptable, since after all that's what editing the content into the question makes this comment.

Comment: Oh, right.. there is the point.. Alright.. It was last year because I never went on raising such `flags` but just kept on my work of editing question whenever someone posted the code as comment.. But now I understood that before raising such flags, we have to mention that _we have done it for the OP, please delete this_. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to do so. An obsolete flag would be just as acceptable.

Comment: Alright buddy.. Thanks for the info.